# hammer.js - different swipe handlers on parent and child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I use hammer.js to bind swipe event handlers (while this is also a basic jquery problem).

```
<div id="container">
   ...
   <div id="entry">Swipe to delete this entry.</div>
   ...
</div>
```

If user swipe on the entry div, I want to add a line through it. If the user swipe on other area of the container div (the srcElement may be other child elements), I want to fold the container. How can I implement this elegantly (now I bind a swipe handler to the container and check if event.target is not the entry div, but this won't work if there are many entries.)

Comment: Did you try event.currentTarget?

Comment: The problem is I want to make it general, not case by case, as there would be other type of child nodes. In other words, I want it automatically call the child A's listener if swipe starts at child A family, child B's listern if at child B family, or the parent listener otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use the "not" selector to deal with the swipe event on the rest parts other than the entry div. So for each entry I can add a class on it and use two kinds of listeners then.
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/